# Apache Mod Rewrite For Front Controller Pattern

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _service.php?uri=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Only problem is there is no rewrite happening and I simply see a directory listing when attempting to access the root page of the server `localhost`.

Even when I try to make the match optional `RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ _service.php?uri=$1 [NC,L]` it does not work.

The rewrite seems fine for any other case e.g. `localhost/foo/bar`

How do I get the rewrite to happen for this particular case?

Comment: What do you want to proxy to when user is accessing root dir? For example, localhost/foo/bar will proxy to service.php?uri=foo/bar, so should root go to uri=/ . Simple way to proxy root is to hardcode RewriteRule ^$ _service.php?uri=/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the root is a directory. So this condition is preventing your rule from getting applied:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Try adding a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^$ _service.php?uri=/ [NC,L]
```

or something

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the document root in order for the file or directory to be found; my variation on this pattern is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA,B]
```

The root page is served correctly (for me) in this case (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`). NB, I have this in `vhost.conf` and not in a `.htaccess`.